# React-Rails Unexpected Token Error for any function other than render()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I am getting an unexpected token error whenever I add any function before `render()`.

For example:

```
var App = React.createClass({

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      notebooks: {}
    };
  }

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div style={{"height": "100%"}}>
        <NotebookNav notebooks={this.props.notebooks}></NotebookNav>
        <Technique></Technique>      
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This component compiles fine when I delete the `constructor()` function, but with `constructor()`, it throws the unexpected token error pointing at `render: function()`.  Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to either use the ES6 `class` syntax or add a comma (`,`) after the `constructor() {...}` code.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing syntax here. `createClass` takes an object as an argument, not an ES6 class. Objects need commas separating items. Also, plain objects don't have a constructor like class does. In React's createClass object spec you probably want `getInitialState` instead

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() { 
    return { notebooks: {} }
  }, // <--- comma
  render() {...}
})
```

you could however rewrite the entire thing using an ES6 class (which does not have commas separating methods.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      notebooks: {}
    };
  } // <--- no comma

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{"height": "100%"}}>
        <NotebookNav notebooks={this.props.notebooks}></NotebookNav>
        <Technique></Technique>      
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear.  My previous React experience was with React Native, where I used ES6, and the React-Rails component generator produces the createClass syntax.  I didn't realize the ramifications of that change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because you are not separating the function with a comma. You should write it like this

```
var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    notebooks: {}
  };
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div style={{"height": "100%"}}>
      <NotebookNav notebooks={this.props.notebooks}></NotebookNav>
      <Technique></Technique>      
    </div>
  );
 }
});
```

also should be `this.state.notebooks` not `this.props.notebook`